# Application insights - telemetry correlation

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

Azure application insights instance, incorporated with my web api application.

Now I have records available across request, exception, & dependencies tables but don't know how to correlate the records across these tables? Which column of which table should be considered, to correlate a particular request related records across the other tables. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can correlate the telemetry using the `operation_Id` property. If you know the `operation_Id` of a given request you can perform a search in the logs:

`search operation_Id == "b9ca1e2671e1814a8e8a754e7b8578f7"`

This will return all telemetry belonging to that request.

For a much more details see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation).